# butt, bottom, buttock and ass?

Tags: vocabulary

> *A woman's butt was allegedly touched by a man several times during a commute on the MRT.*

How to use butt, bottom, buttock and ass?
I am confusing with these words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In AmE:

butt - The typical word used (except in formal company).

bottom - What immediately comes to mind with "bottom" is a parent-child relationship.  For example, a mother would say this about her child - "If you don't stop I'm going to smack your bottom."  Someone else may say this to an intimate partner trying to be coy, shy, or "cute."  Definitely informal.

buttock - It's *buttocks*, and it's not heard a lot outside of a reference to the Forrest Gump movie or possibly a medical context.  This would probably be most appropriate in a formal situation.  (EDIT: Briefly looking at searches it seems this was originally a diminutive form of *butt* - so my initial supposition that this is a full form of "butt" is not correct.)

ass - Vulgar, don't use in polite or unknown company.

Comment: -1 *butt* is informal and not used in formal (and perhaps not polite) contexts; your example sentence for *bottom* does not necessarily coincide with any of the adjectives you use for the word; *buttocks* is often used. And if you aren't going to take the trouble to find out if *buttock* is the origin of *butt,* don't bother to answer. Guesses don't do the OP any good.

Comment: Also (until recently) quite strongly marked as foreign (US) in British English. "Ass" is the American English for British English "Arse".

Comment: @CarSmack: You're right.  I edited.

Comment: There are other words besides these four that could be used, too, like _rear end_ (or even just _rear_) and _behind_. The _behind_ option might be a good alternative if the O.P. is looking for something not too formal but not too vulgar, either.

Comment: did not -1 but would strongly caution against using "butt" with strangers -- it is a little crass. "rear end" is better.

Answer (score 17):

*butt* is far more common in AmE than in BrE, though has become more common since the 1980s: See this [Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20butt%2C%20his%20backside&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20butt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20backside%3B%2Cc0)  We Brits prefer 'backside.

*bottom* is a fairly innocuous word.

*buttock* - this is one half of your backside. We use it commonly if we are talking to the doctor about a problem we have in one. It's also commonly used in the plural in (semi-)formal language  *The punishment is usually administered either across the buttocks or on the hands* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_corporal_punishment.

An *ass* is a donkey in BrE. A cruder word for backside is *a**r**s**e***, the BrE equivalent of AmE **ass**.

Comment: +1 Would like to add that 'ass' in AmE is the equivalent of arse in BrE.

Comment: @michelle: done

Comment: +1 for making the US/British English distinctions. Buttock appears to be understood on both sides of the Atlantic, albeit that it is only one half.

Comment: I would add that the latter is not just _cruder_, but is usually considered vulgar/offensive, at least in the U.S. Also, 'backside' is used in the U.S., too, and is considered pretty much equivalent to 'backside' here.